# Unable to run docker commands on windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-for-windows

i am very new to Docker and i have recently started learning it.

I was not unable  to install docker directly as my windows OS is not Windows 10 Professional or Enterprise. I am using Windows 10 home with 16 GB ram.
So I downloaded the latest version of Docker Tool Box and opened the Docker QuickStart Terminal after some I see a message as below.

"This machine has been allocated an IP address, but Docker Machine could not
reach it successfully.

SSH for the machine should still work, but connecting to exposed ports, such as
the Docker daemon port (usually :2376), may not work properly.

You may need to add the route manually, or use another related workaround.

This could be due to a VPN, proxy, or host file configuration issue.

You also might want to clear any VirtualBox host only interfaces you are not using.
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.99.100:2376": dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: i/o timeout
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.

Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.99.100:2376": dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: i/o timeout
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers."

Also i am unable to execute simple docker commands. I tried to execute a the command "docker pull hello-world" but i am unble to do so as i see the below response on the terminal.

"error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=hello-world&tag=latest: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running."

i have searched for some solutions online but most of the solutions seem to be doable for Linux users. Can someone please let me know how can I get these issues resolved on the windows machine.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with kitematics and select use virtualbox. Also run it as administrator

Comment: @Sandhu   i have tried with kitematics and selected "use virtualbox " but could see a response after some time as "stderr maxBuffer exceeded".